# Most efficient way to pull information from a table

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

As a new-to-python person the only way that I can think of to grab information from a table (separated by only whitespace) is to call an item by its position using the row and column its located in. I've been using numpy a lot like so:

```
information_table=np.array([]) #The table I'm pulling data from

info_i_need_from_table=information_table[i][j] #Where i/j is the location of whatever info I need
```

Is this the optimal way of grabbing information from a table? I'm new to python so as far as I know this is the only way to do it, but I'd be willing to bet I'm wrong. Say my `information_table` is fairly large, thousands of rows, hundreds of colums. Would you utilize the same 'tool' to pull information from, say, a much smaller table?

As an example of *one* of the tables I'm working with:

```
/SAH/SAH5/jimunoz/DUSTYlib2/models_Y100_699K/COMPACTs3300_Al_g+1.5_m1.0_t02_st_z-0.25.inp  3300  699  1.000E+02  Al2O3  1.06E+05  1.26E-05  1.70E+14  81  2.61E-10  0.360484737991  0.77871386826  1.03440307618  0.568135259544  0.157877963222  0.0791445961324  0.0398783584044  0.0159762347055  0.000741792598059  
/SAH/SAH5/jimunoz/DUSTYlib2/models_Y100_699K/COMPACTs3300_Al_g+1.5_m1.0_t02_st_z-0.25.inp  3300  699  1.000E+02  Al2O3  1.06E+05  1.60E-05  1.70E+14  81  3.12E-10  0.360484737991  0.77871386826  1.03440307618  0.568135259544  0.157877963222  0.0791445961324  0.0398783584044  0.0159762347055  0.000741792620505
```

Those are just the first two rows. Another table I may be working with would just have numerous rows and columns of floating point numbers (at about 5 sig-figs).

Comment: Given no information other than that `[]` is your table, yes, the 2D-array method (`[row][col]`) is indeed the most direct way to access a table.

Comment: Would there be a difference then from using numpy arrays vs. python's native arrays?

Comment: could you print the first row / column of your table so we can see it?

Comment: @seth see edit. I wanted to keep it general, but maybe there is something I don't know about specific tables and ways to access them.

Comment: @Matt Not really, as long as the whole thing fits into memory. Accessing by index is O(1). (I'm not sure how numpy handles datasets that are too large to read into RAM, but I'd trust them to make index lookup fast since it's not a hard problem.)